# confused about the value of current in the circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Its a simple question and i am sorry if the question is repeated.Here in the given figure i am confused about the value of **i2** .Is it 20 A or 0 A ?

[image]

Comment: We have a schematic editor here. Please use it instead of hand drawings so that the question (and schematic) is clear.

Comment: The current paths in your circuit should be better labeled in order for this question to be clearer. I assume i1 is the current path through the 1ohm resistor, i2 is the current path through the wire on the right and that the current path through the 2ohm resistor is unlabeled. It would be best if you could either confirm of correct this.

Comment: I didn't know about schematic editor. I will use it next time. Thanks guys for helping me out

Answer (score 3):

I2 appears to be a dead short. So all the current (20A) will flow through I2 and essentially zero current through the 2 ohm resistor (I1).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to think about getting the solution:

Suppose the current \$i_2\$ were 0.

Then what would be the current through the 2-ohm resistor?

Given that, what is the voltage across the 2-ohm resistor?

Therefore, what is the voltage across the short circuit branch labelled with \$i_2\$?

Is that number consistent with having no current through a short circuit?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the current by this way

Req =((2*0)/(2+0))+1

Req=0+1

the 2Ω resistor is in parallel with wire (0Ω)

so 2Ω resistor is shorted

Req=1Ω

so the current can be

I=v/R

I=20/1=20A